# How do I get the form up if the radio button is checked? (AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am facing problems while writing a program that has 3 radio buttons, each radio button, when checked, should display a small form on the part of the same webpage. I am using AJAX and PHP. My question is, how do I write the function to display the corresponding form if a radio button is checked? Please note that I am new to AJAX/PHP.

```
<input type="radio" 
       name="RadioGroup1" 
       value="radio" 
       id="RadioGroup1_0" 
       onclick="showView()" />
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the importance of AJAX or PHP to your question. Are these forms being loaded via AJAX? Or are you POSTing the initial form with the radio button which then loads the correct form? Otherwise this seems more like a Javascript question to me

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to load the forms using AJAX. I would like to know how this can be done using JavaScript.

Comment: No problem, do you have any basic source you're working with? Also, are you using any libraries such as jQuery?

Comment: I am not using jquery. Here is more information about the problem statement: I need to design a webpage which is similar to the recurrence appointment form in the MS Outlook. So I have 3 radio buttons for each of Daily, Weekly and Monthly. And now I need to display the corresponding form on selection of a radio button.

Comment: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0" onclick="showView()"/>

Here is the part of the code. I want to implement the function showView(). Please tell me if this can be done in a better way if we use jQuery.

Comment: It seems to me this is outside the scope of a normal Stack Overflow question given that there are plenty of Ajax tutorials online that will explain how to load content when something is clicked. Using JQuery (or some other library) will certainly simplify it too, taking care of cross-browser issues automatically. Having said that, for the specific purpose you mention I think you're better off *not* using Ajax: just have all three forms as part of the main page but start them off hidden then just hide/show with CSS/JS as appropriate.

Comment: @rahul_desai Your question is lacking very importance information. Are your forms in an external file? Are you using any JavaScript library (other than jQuery, since you stated you weren't using that)? Please provide us with more information so we can better assist you.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Yes, each of my forms are in separate files. I have a div wherein I want the corresponding form to be displayed on clicking a radio button. When I click on other radio button, a different form should be displayed in the same div, replacing the previous one. I am using JavaScript but not jQuery. I will use it if it makes my life easy.

PLEASE NOTE THAT I AM NOT COMPELLED TO USE AJAX OR ANY OTHER TECHNOLOGY/LANGUAGE. If things are easier just by using JavaScript/jQuery, I will go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally? I would hold them each in a div and conditionally display them. Unless you have really good cause, there is no reason you can't load this up front (and it introduces another point of failure to use AJAX to actually load the div's here).

```
function hideElements()
{
    // using jQuery, I would probably loop and use a class selector here.
    // but this is an example.
    document.getElementById("tag1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("tag2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("tag3").style.display = "none";
}
```

As your listener on the radio buttons (probably through something like $("#tag1, #tag2, #tag3).click, if you're using jQuery, onclick or addEventListener if you're doing this bare-bones)

```
function showElement( tag ) //tag == "tag1" through "tag3"
{
    hideElements();
    document.getElementById("tag1").style.display = "inline"
}
```

If AJAX is a must (back-end logic is a requirement for whether the form is shown), I would *still* load them up front and only conditionally display the forms based off of the response from the back-end.